# Why does the C++ compiler require a "typename" keyword in this particular case?

Tags: c++

I just figured out that C++ requires a typename in the following code (see the member function definition at the end of the code fragment):

```
template <typename T> struct ClassWithSubtype
{
    struct Sub
    {
        //static void check( const ClassWithSubtype<T>::Sub& sub );
        ClassWithSubtype<T>::Sub& operator=( const ClassWithSubtype<T>::Sub& other );
    };
};

/*
//Here C++ does not require a typename for the argument type
template <typename T> void ClassWithSubtype<T>::Sub::check( const ClassWithSubtype<T>::Sub& sub )
{
    //do sth.
}
*/

//Here C++ requires a typename for the return type
template <typename T> typename ClassWithSubtype<T>::Sub& ClassWithSubtype<T>::Sub::operator=( const ClassWithSubtype<T>::Sub& other )
{
    //do sth.
}
```

I can completely understand that C++ requires the keyword `typename` for the return type. What I do not understand is why NO `typename` is needed for the argument type of the example function `check` (which is commented out). Furthermore, why is a `typename` required in the definition of the assignment operator, but not in its declaration?

Comment: "current instantiation" and complicated rules related thereto, make the declaration work.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: But I hope it is not compiler dependent... In other words: is it correct to leave out the typename in the declaration? What about the function arguments???

Comment: Inside the class body, the `typename` keyword is not required.  Outside the class body, it is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two rules together (both in 14.6.2.1) yield the observed behavior:

First, that

> A name refers to the current instantiation if it is
>
> - in the deﬁnition of a class template, a nested class of a class template, a member of a class template, or a member of a nested class of a class template, the *injected-class-name* (Clause 9) of the class template or nested class,
> - in  the  deﬁnition  of  a  primary  class  template  or  a  member  of  a  primary  class  template,  the  name  of  the class template followed by the template argument list of the primary template (as described below)
>     enclosed in `<>` (or an equivalent template alias specialization),
> - in  the  deﬁnition  of  a  nested  class  of  a  class  template,  the  name  of  the  nested  class  referenced  as  a
>     member of the current instantiation, or

and one more unrelated bullet point.

Then,

> A name is a member of the current instantiation if it is
>
> - An  unqualified  name  that,  when  looked  up,  refers  to  at  least  one  member  of  a  class  that  is  the  current instantiation or a non-dependent base class thereof.  [ Note:  **This can only occur when looking up a name in a scope enclosed by the definition of a class template.**  — end note ]

and two unrelated bullet points.

Therefore, in both cases, `ClassWithSubType<T>` refers to the current instantiation.  But as the note explains, `Sub` refers to a member of the current instantiation only when used inside the class template body.  In the out-of-class definition, it becomes a "member of an unknown specialization".

As a member of the current instantiation, the compiler determines that `Sub` is a class type.

Outside the class body, the compiler doesn't know this and the `typename` keyword is needed.

Comment: Basically, in those cases you can even remove the explicit template parameter `<T>`.  It made sense to me when I realized that and starts to look more like a non-dependent name.

Comment: @GuyGreer: You could even say `Sub` without further qualification, since it is the injected class name.